# Adding an array in numpy at a specified location

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a fast way in numpy to add array A to array B *at a specified location*?

For instance, if

```
B = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7]
]
```

and

```
A = [
    [2, 2],
    [2, 2]
]
```

and I want to add A to B starting from point (0, 0) to get

```
C = [
    [2, 3, 2],
    [4, 5, 4],
    [5, 6, 7],
]
```

Of course I can do that via extending the array A to match the shape of B and then using numpy.roll, but it seems unnecessarily slow if the size of A is much much smaller then size of B.

EDIT:

potentially with wrapping around - ie such that bottom row of A is added to the top row of B and top row of A is added to the bottom row of B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify B in place

```
B[:2,:2] += A
```

otherwise

```
C = B.copy()
C[:2,:2] += A
```

Comment: Great! is there any easy way to add a wrap-around though?
B[-2:2, -2:2] does not seem to do anything meaningful =(